# Split comma separated entries to new rows with a second value in column B

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to separate a worksheet that has multiple cells values in column A separated by a comma,and a price against it in column B. I found the Macro for splitting the multiple cells in Column A but not sure how to add the column B value thats associated with Column A Value.

I would like the new values to be copied into column C & D so I can check it has worked ok.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it is a lot of cells to do manually.

```
(Cell A1) 33
(Cell A2) 333, 334, 3389, 3398, 33876                    
(Cell A3) 44, 447, 44797, 44819
(Cell A4) 52, 5255, 5237, 523700

(Cell B1) 0.0053
(Cell B2) 0.0124
(Cell B3) 0.0089
(Cell B4) 0.0156
```

Comment: what is layout for your desired output?

Comment: I don't see why this question is tagged with `sql`

Comment: In the future please remember to show the code you've got.

Answer (score 1):

The results would be similar if ColumnA were copied to ColumnC and then Text to Columns applied to ColumnC, with `,` as the delimiter.

By special request, via Record Macro:

```
   Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar _
        :="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5,1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
  End Sub
```

or an abbreviated version

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng1 = [A:A]
    Set rng2 = [C:C]
    rng1.Copy rng2
    rng2.Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Comma:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5,1))
End Sub
```

Comment: In fact why don't you post a vba method as well which will do what you mentioned above? I am sure it will faster than looping every cell?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, K As Long, J As Long, I As Long
    J = 1
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For K = 1 To N
        ary = Split(Cells(K, 1).Value, ",")
        v = Cells(K, 2).Value
        For I = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            Cells(J, 3).Value = ary(I)
            Cells(J, 4) = v
            J = J + 1
        Next I
    Next K
End Sub
```